# Generate a TOC using all markdown files in GitHub repo

Tags: github, markdown, tableofcontents

I have a GitHub repo that has a bunch of common reusable React components that can be imported into other projects. Each component has its own README.md file with instructions on how to use the component with required props and so on.

These components are set up in an atomic structure, atoms, molecules and organisms. I am trying to find a library, hopefully running in node, to run locally that will go through my directory tree find all the README.md files and create a Table of Contents. So far I have only been able to find ones that create a TOC from within a single file. But I need one that will create a TOC of all my .md files.